# R Data extraction and cleaning

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to clean the data set by

1. Removing the rows with text values for a numeric column
2. And splitting the ast.range column into astUpper and astLower columns for the upper and lower range values.

so that I can perform some aggregations of the data to find some insights.

I am new to R, just started learning.
Any suggestion to what another approach I can take to obtain clean and consisted data is welcomed.

[image: A snapshot of my data is included]

Comment: Please post a small reproducible example using `dput` instead of images

Comment: It’s hard to give any detail without a reproducible example, but you should read through the manual for the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages. They are (in my opinion) the easiest and simplest way to work with data frames and should be able to do whatever you want.

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site. I advise you to load your data into Rstudio. This is very helpful to clean your data.  Then save it as a data.frame. So you can work quite easy. Could you please do these two steps.

Comment: First install Rstudio, if you do not have it. Then, load your data. After that use this: `Mydata <- as.data.frame(yourdata name)`. Then, please rewrite your question with some part of the new look of your data.

Comment: I really would like to help. I found this site which may help you. Please have a look http://rprogramming.net/recode-data-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help you or not since your data cannot be reproducible. I generate some data for you.

```
 y <- c("x", 10, 11)
 x <- c("t", 20, 15)
```

Then, I bind these data by column, like this:

```
xy <- cbind(y,x)
```

Then, you will get this:

```
 y x
1  x t
2 10 20
3 11 15
```

After that, I convert it to a `data.frame` using the following code:

```
mydata <- as.data.frame(xy)
```

After that, you can select column by column to clean your data, using this code:

```
mydata$y <- as.numeric(as.character(mydata$y))
```

This code will replace any text with NA or you can set it to 0 is you like.

The output is this:

`> mydata
   y x
1 NA t
2 10 20
3 11 15`